# Check object items length

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I am working currently on a filter bar. Using react-hook-form {useForm}.
What I try to achieve as I console.log(watch()) I get back and array of the filter form items,

I can see it contains my filter items all cool. I have dates as string and autocomplete fields as array.

On to the point I have a defaultValues object with all field empty, so no default filter. I want to compare defaultValues (which is empty fields) with watch items, so if I have active filters I want to count them and give back the number in the filter bar as a number.

Could you please help me how to compare them and also count if watch() item not empty, null or undefined than increase count.

```
export const defaultValues = {
id: [],
dateFrom: '',
dateTo: '',
numbers: [],
cars: [],
}
```

console.log(wathc()) response:

```
{id: Array(2), dateTo: "2022-04-31T00:00:00.000Z", dateFrom: "", cars: Array(0), numbers: Array(0)}
```

One of the array has 2 items, and one of is not an empty string. I want to count them up and in the Filter Bar (3) so that we have 3 active filter.

I aslo do have a url parser:

```
export const parseURLFilters = (search, setDefaultIfEmpty) => {
  const queryParams = queryString.parse(search, {
    parseBooleans: true,
    parseNumbers: true,
  });
  const filters = {};
  Object.entries(defaultValues).forEach(([key, defaultValue]) => {
    const queryParamValue = queryParams[key];

    if (setDefaultIfEmpty || (!setDefaultIfEmpty && queryParamValue)) {
      if (queryParamValue && isArray(defaultValue)) {
        // Parse array query param values correctly
        filters[key] = isArray(queryParamValue) ? queryParamValue : [queryParamValue];
      } else {
        filters[key] = queryParamValue || defaultValue;
      }
    }
  });
  return filters;
};
```

If I console.log(parseURLFilters(location.search)) I get back only the field with actual value:

```
{
id: Array(2), dateTo: "2022-04-31T00:00:00.000Z",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check the object equality while keeping a variable to count the different values (`count`). Additionally, do a deep check for array values.

```js
const defaultValues = {
  id: [],
  dateFrom: '',
  dateTo: '',
  numbers: [],
  cars: [],
}

const newValues = {
  id: [1,2], 
  dateTo: "2022-04-31T00:00:00.000Z", 
  dateFrom: "", 
  cars: [], 
  numbers: []
}

const checkEqualArray = (arr1, arr2) => {
     arr1.sort();
     arr2.sort();
     return arr1.length === arr2.length && arr1.every((val, index) => val === arr2[index]);
}

const getTotalFilters = (obj1, obj2) => {
    let count = 0;
    for(const key in obj1) {
    if(obj1.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if(Array.isArray(obj1[key]) && Array.isArray(obj2[key])) {
        count += !checkEqualArray(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
      } else {
        count += obj1[key] !== obj2[key];
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(count);
}

getTotalFilters(defaultValues, newValues);
```

Comment: I just found a code that makes it easier if you could fix your comment based on it, I put it in the original description.